# NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: swift, alamofire

> my error is
>   unsuccessfullresponseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 3." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 3.}))
>
> here my webservice by alamofire

```
IBAction func loginbtn(_ sender: Any) {
        runPutRequest()
    }

func runPutRequest() {

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "UserName" : "ABC",
        "Password" : "pass"
        ]

    func runPutRequest() {

    let par: Parameters = [
        "UserName" : "dominic.koh@circle8.asia",
        "Password" : "password2"
        ]

    let header: HTTPHeaders = [ "Accept": "application/json" ]

    Alamofire.request("http://circle8.asia:8081/Onet.svc/UserLogin",method:.post, parameters: par , encoding: URLEncoding.queryString,headers:header).responseJSON { (resDataLogin) -> Void in
    //    print(resDataLogin)
        switch  resDataLogin.result
        {
        case.success(let data) :
            print("YOUR Details>>  ",data)
            break
        case.failure(let error) :
            print("unsuccessfull\(error)");
            break
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: in error "unsuccessfullresponseSerializationFailed" it's not able to serialize the json response. This means you are not getting response as json. check if some html tag or xml is present in response. Since you are doing .responseJSON so response should be json.

Comment: i have add  let header: HTTPHeaders = [ "Accept": "application/json" ] but still getting same error. @manismku

Comment: ok. You can also go and check if response is valid json on http://jsoneditoronline.org/. There is non json value as showing in error "Invalid value around character 3"

Comment: responce is proper @manismku

Comment: Check the received JSON. The error message *Invalid value around character 3* is pretty clear.

Comment: Has this issue resolved?